# How to inject content page with form data after submission?

Tags: squarespace

When you build a form on Squarespace, you can redirect the user to another content page on form submission. Is there a way to inject values from that form to the new content page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to do it with the following approach, assuming that the page you are redirecting to is on the same domain:

1. Add a [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) listener to the form. This should not interfere with Squarespace's own submission functionality.
2. Within the function called by the listener, serialize the form's data/fields.
3. Store the serialized data within [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).
4. Access the sessionStorage data on the new page.
5. Parse the serialized data if necessary and utilize it within a function on the new page.

If the new page is instead on a separate domain, then things would be done similarly except that instead of using Squarespace's own feature for setting the new landing page, you'd use JavaScript to set the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location), passing the sessionStorage data as query parameters to the new page.